# Sanity - How to populate a list of predefined strings based on another field in the same document?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sanity

I want to make a section field which it's options will be based on the category value

I tried this but it didn't work

```
defineField({
      name: 'category',
      type: 'string',
      title: 'Category',
      options: {list: ['food', 'grocery', 'food stuff', 'super market']},
      initialValue: 'food',
      validation: (rule) => rule.required(),
    }),
    defineField({
      name: 'section',
      type: 'string',
      hidden: ({document}) => !document?.category,
      options: {
        list: ({document}) => {
          const selectedCategory = document.category
          return selectedCategory === 'food' ? ['option 0', 'option 1'] : ['option 2', 'option 3']
        },
      },
    }),
```